# A JSX element doesn't show it's content

Tags: html, reactjs, tailwind-css

I am new to React. I'm trying to make a navbar for my app. But I encounter a few problems

- the contents of the `<Btn></Btn>` is not visible
- the css doesn't affects anything

Tools that I use:

- Firefox with react developer extension
- Ubuntu 23.04
- VS Code
- Tailwindcss

my index.js file

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './twcss-out.css';

//Import when we need routing in the future
/*import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Routes,
  Route,
  Navigate,
} from "react-router-dom";
*/

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));

/* FOR TESTING ONLY
const Test = (props) => {
  let {title, sectionTitle} = props;
  return (
    <div>
      <h1 className='font-sans'>{title}</h1>
      <p className='font-sans'>{sectionTitle}</p>
      <hr/>
    </div>
  )
}
*/
const Btn = ({content, extraClasses}) => {
  return (
    <button type='button' className={'bg-primary text-white p-2 rounded'+extraClasses}>{content}</button>
  );
}


const RootDiv = () => {
  const textFormatting = {
    B: ' font-bold',
    I: ' font-italic',
    U: ' underline'
  }
  const {B, I, U} = textFormatting; 
  return (
    <div>
      <nav className='bg-primary flex flex-1 flex-col'>
        <h1 className='text-xl font-bold text-white py-2 ms-1'>SkyPress</h1>
        <section role='toolbar' className='rounded bg-green-300 grid grid-cols-3 '>
          <section role='group' className='btn-group'>
              <Btn extraClasses={B}>B</Btn>
              <Btn extraClasses={I}>I</Btn>
              <Btn extraClasses={U}>U</Btn> 
          </section>
        </section>
      </nav>      
    </div>
  ); 
}

root.render(
  <RootDiv/>
);
```

my index.html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta
      name="description"
      content="Web site created using create-react-app"
    />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../src/twcss-out.css">
    <style>
      .btn-group:first-child {
        border-top-left-radius: 0.25rem;
        border-bottom-left-radius: 0.25rem;
      }
      .btn-group:last-child {
          border-top-right-radius: 0.25rem;
          border-bottom-right-radius: 0.25rem;
      }
    </style>
    <title>React App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>Please enable javascript</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script src="../src/index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

my console outputs and error

[console output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IK0qi.png)

also I see something interesting in the devtools panel

[interesting devtools panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OAJHU.png)

Look at the button element. It somehow doesn't have anything inside it but in the index.js file there's the letter B, I and U inside of it

I tried reading the react docs, and ofcourse don't get any info
I also tried adding the letters B, I, and U to the respective buttons through devtools, it worked and the style are applied, but ofcourse I can't tell the user to click f12 and fix that for me everytime

Comment: looks like you did not build/transpile your react code. the browser cant natively handle the css import, nor the jsx syntax

Comment: thanks, for the answer. But I just found out that I must use the content props, which I totally forgot. I'll close this question, I mean delete

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rename the `content` prop to `children`.

```
const Btn = ({children, extraClasses}) => {
  return (
    <button type='button' className={'bg-primary text-white p-2 rounded'+extraClasses}>{children}</button>
  );
}
```

See https://react.dev/learn/passing-props-to-a-component#passing-jsx-as-children

---

Alternatively you can explicitly pass the value for that `content` prop :

```
<Btn extraClasses={B} content='B'/>
```

Comment: ok thanks, got it working.